# Clean up the list of options shown when opening my Gmail account

Tags: google-multi-login

When opening Gmail (email account) - clicking on the Gmail icon opens my daily account but I have others - so I highlight the daily email address and a dialogue box opens with possible options, including other email addresses I use or attempted to create.

I want to take those out - delete them. I don't like how junky it has gotten through the years. How do I delete these address/attempted addresses from the Gmail address dialogue box?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a remove option below the list of accounts.

Try going to Google.com and signing in there.

If you still don't see it sign in one of the other account is then sign out and try to sign in again and it should appear.

If not sign in to your preffered account and then disable the account chooser in the browser

https://www.google.com/accounts/optintoaccountchoosr/optout=1